# Rails 6 + Active Storage : set a default image that can have a variant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6, minimagick

I need to set a default image for active storage attachments, in case of no image was uploaded.

I could make a simple helper calling an image from `/assets/images` but in this case, those images won't work with variants (e.g. `<%= image_tag image.variant(resize_to_fill: [50,50]) %>`)

Browsing the web, I found this interesting article that gives some clues : https://gorails.com/forum/how-do-i-set-and-use-a-default-image-with-active-storage, but it is not enough for my case.

Attaching the image with a `before_create` callback sounds overkill to me, as it is going to upload the same image several times to the storage.

- Is there a way to set a default picture that is going to behave like any Active Storage attachment, and accepts variants ?
- Is there a way to make minimagick variants working with "normal" images from assets path ?

Comment: With `before_create` you can assign one blob to many objects. Note that `Attachment` is what your object has, while `Blob` is what resides in a service like S3. You could check docs https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attachment.html and inspect relationship between attachment and blob

Answer (score 1):

Create a Method to fetch image . Follow the below snippet:

```
  def fetch_cover_image
    if self.cover_image.attached?
      Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_url(self.cover_image, 
       host: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:host])
    else
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url('cover_image.jpg')
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a good clue but it does not solve the issue as explained in my post, since the default image does not accepts the variants : `undefined method 'variant' for #<String:0x00007fcc79828f00>`